# HQL: OR clause returning less records rather than more

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I have an Employee model which has a Manager field that can either be null, or point to another Employee.

I'm trying to run a query that will pull back a list of Employees that sit below a certain Manager in the hierarchy.  So I started with the following WHERE clause:

```
(e.Manager.Id = :managerId or 
  (e.Manager is not null and e.Manager.Manager.Id = :managerId))
```

Which seems to work fine, returning Employees who's manager is the specified manager, or who's manager is MANAGED BY the specified manager.

I try to take it to the next level:

```
(e.Manager.Id = :managerId or 
  (e.Manager is not null and e.Manager.Manager.Id = :managerId) or 
  (e.Manager.Manager is not null and e.Manager.Manager.Manager.Id = :managerId))
```

Which then brings back ONLY employees who's manager is MANAGED BY the specified manager.  Employees who are managed by the specified manager are NOT returned.

How can this be?  Surely if the first part of the clause is a match (managed by the specified manager) then the rest of the clause shouldn't even be evaluated?

Comment: I would use explicit join for this query.  (What happens if e.Manager is null?)

Comment: @BadZen Could you give me an example of how you'd write that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without explicit JOINs, sometimes, Hibernate get lost and can't generate the query that the developer thinks that should be generated.

So, a good practice is always explicit your JOINs (as @Badzen adviced).

I couldn't test the query, but try that:

```
Select e FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN e.manager m1
LEFT JOIN m1.manager m2
LEFT JOIN m2.manager m3
WHERE m1.id = :managerId 
   or (m1 IS NOT NULL and m2.id = :managerId) 
   or (m2 IS NOT NULL and m3.id = :managerId)
```

In this way the generated query is predictable and is easier to understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This SQL statement should work if you don't have even more levels of management than you mention in your question.

```
select e1.* from Employee e1 
left join Employee manager on e1.manager = manager.id
left join Employee bigManager on manager.manager = bigManager.id
where e1.manager = 3 or manager.manager = 3 or bigManager.manager = 3
```

*3 is just the id of the manager I used when testing this in my db*